# Htaccess Hide File Extention and Keep $_GET parameter to be Access

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First of all I have 2 file which is index.php and main.php, inside both file I already include the $_GET parameter so it can be access by using this

```
index.php?page=login
index.php?page=register&ref=1 
main.php?page=member
main.php?page=member&edit
main.php?page=logout
```

by using .htaccess I want to remove the .php extention but I want to keep the parameter and access it with a new url

I made this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php?\?p=([^\s]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php?\?p=([^\s]+)&[A-Z]=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1?/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ main.php?p=$1  [L,QSA]
```

Yes I can access index.php with only http://ex.com/index and main.php http://ex.com/main, but take a look at this code

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ main.php?p=$1  [L,QSA]
```

When the "index.php" rule is in the top, I can access http://ex.com/login or http://ex.com/register (parameters in index.php) but can't access http://ex.com/member or http://ex.com/logout (parameter in main.php)

What I want is to have access to all file by using parameter or not.
thanks

Comment: You can't have two identical patterns and expect both to work. How would Apache know which match you want when if they are identical? Where should `/foo` be redirected? To index.php or main.php?

Comment: any suggestion to have another htaccess rule? or to give a slash to url so it will be http://ex.com/index/register and http://ex.com/main/member

Comment: If you hard code a prefix like that, then you just need to change your patterns to: `^index/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1` and `^main/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ main.php?p=$1`. Personally, I prefer handling URL's using a router instead. Then it's a part of the application instead of a part of the web server configuration.

Comment: any reference to use router?

Comment: Just google "php router" and you will find a lot of libraries and examples.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code to use

```
RewriteRule ^register/?$ index.php?p=register  [L]
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?p=login  [L]
RewriteRule ^member/?$ main.php?p=member  [L]
RewriteRule ^logout/?$ main.php?p=logout  [L]
```

but yes the parameter can be access by something or what. Just want to find out more.